# List comprehension: Creating new list by adding multiple values in single list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given a list containing monthly numerical data, how can I easily convert this into quarterly data?

```
x= [5,8,3,4,5,6,1,2,5,3,11,8] #monthly data for Jan-Dec
```

Desired output:

```
[5+8+3, 4+5+6, 1+2+5, 3+11+8] #converted to quarterly data
```

I wanted to do something like `[a+b+c for a,b,c in x]` but x it says x is not iterable.

I don't think this is a duplicate. I am specifically looking for a list comprehension solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension way:

```
[sum([x[i],x[i+1],x[i+2]]) for i in range(0,len(x),3)]
#[16, 15, 8, 22]
```

Or in a nicer way (thanks @JonClements):

```
[sum(x[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
```

And a `numpy` way:

```
import numpy as np

np.sum(np.array(x).reshape(-1,3),axis=1)
#array([16, 15,  8, 22])
```

Comment: That `sum` part can be simplified... `[sum(x[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]`

Comment: Dude @JonClements is a beast, he's everywhere on here, ha I even watched the youtube clip of his Dr. Who quote, this did is a monster <3

Answer (score 0):

Not getting to crazy you could just slice them up and then work with each group

```
x= [5,8,3,4,5,6,1,2,5,3,11,8]

a, b, c, d = x[:3], x[3:6], x[6:9], x[9:12]

print(a, b, c, d)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 slice_q.py 
> [5, 8, 3] [4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 5] [3, 11, 8]
> ```

From here if you want to sum each group you could do something like this

```
lista = [a, b, c, d,]

for i in lista:
    print(sum(i))
```

> ```
> 16
> 15
> 8
> 22
> ```